# Am I understanding this right? (function defined with equivalence relation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I was given this question (there were prior questions defining the equivelence relation ~)

Let $E$ be the set of equivelence classes of $\sim$. Define $f$ from $E$ to $\mathbb R$,
$$f:=\{([(x,y)],r)|x=yr,\: x,y,r\text{ in }\mathbb R\}.$$

I'm trying to understand what it means; is the following correct?

> $f:[(x,y)] \mapsto r$,
>
> $E=(\mathbb R \times {\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}})/\sim$: i.e. the Quotient set of $(\mathbb R\times (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}))$ by $\sim$.
>
> $(x,y)$ was earlier defined as an element of $(\mathbb R \times (\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$.

Am I understanding this right?

My function takes in a equivlence class, $[(x,y)]$ and returns a real value $r$, fufilling the condition that $x=yr$?

Comment: You may want to check your spelling! But I think your basic understanding is more-or-less okay - you'll need to do some work to show that f is well-defined and that depends on the definition of ~.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the function is defined to take equivalence classes as inputs, and return reals as values. If you put in the class of $(x,y)$, which is $[(x,y)] = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{\star}\,|\, (x,y)\sim (a,b)\}$, it returns a real number $r$. Which real number? The real number $r$ such that $x=yr$. (I'm using $\mathbb{R}^{\star}$ to denote the nonzero real numbers) The function takes equivalence classes as inputs, and has real numbers as outputs.

You would need to make sure that this function is *well defined*, though; that is, the definition of the function depends on the name you give the equivalence class; but the class $[(x,y)]$ has many different "names"; it can also be called $[(a,b)]$ for some other real numbers $a$ and $b$. So you need to make sure that if $[(x,y)]=[(a,b)]$ (that is, if $(x,y)\sim (a,b)$) then the real number $r$ such that $x=yr$ is the same as the real number $s$ such that $a=bs$. Otherwise, what you describe would not be a function.

Comment: Good. this is what i've done

Answer (score 2):

That looks right to me.  Recall that a function $f : X \to Y$ is formally a subset of $X \times Y$, i.e. a set of ordered pairs $(x,y), x \in X, y \in Y$, with the property that if $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$ then $y=z$.

Here $X$ is the set $E$ of equivalence classes, and $Y = \mathbb{R}$.  You are told that $f$ is the set of ordered pairs $([(x,y)],r)$ for which $x = yr$.  One has to check that this is well-defined with respect to the equivalence relation ~: if $x=yr$ and $(x,y)~(x',y')$, then $x'=y'r$.  Then $f$ makes sense as a set.  To check that it is a function, one should check that if $([(x,y)], r) \in f$ and $([(x,y)], r') \in f$ (i.e. $x=yr$ and $x=yr'$) then $r=r'$ (which should follow since $y \ne 0$ by assumption).